# c++ split string by double newline

Tags: c++, string, split

I have been trying to split a string by double newlines (`"\n\n"`).

```
input_string = "firstline\nsecondline\n\nthirdline\nfourthline";

size_t current;
size_t next = std::string::npos;
do {
  current = next + 1;
  next = input_string.find_first_of("\n\n", current);
  cout << "[" << input_string.substr(current, next - current) << "]" << endl;
} while (next != std::string::npos);
```

gives me the output

```
[firstline]
[secondline]
[]
[thirdline]
[fourthline]
```

which is obviously not what I wanted. I need to get something like

```
[first line
second line]
[third line
fourthline]
```

I have also tried `boost::split` but it gives me the same result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find_first_of` only looks for single characters.  What you're telling it to do by passing it `"\n\n"`, is to find the first of either `'\n'` or `'\n'`, and that's redundant.  Use [`string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) instead.

`boost::split` also works by examining only one character at a time.

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach:

```
  string input_string = "firstline\nsecondline\n\nthirdline\nfourthline";

  size_t current = 0;
  size_t next = std::string::npos;
  do
  {
    next = input_string.find("\n\n", current);
    cout << "[" << input_string.substr(current, next - current) << "]" << endl;
    current = next + 2;
  } while (next != std::string::npos);
```

It gives me:

```
[firstline
secondline]
[thirdline
fourthline]
```

as the result, which is basically what you wanted, right?

Answer (score -2):

The reason why your code doesn't work is explained very well by @Benjamin in his answer. So I would show you an alternative solution.

No need to do manual splitting. For your specific case, `std::stringstream` is appropriate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
        std::string input = "firstline\nsecondline\n\nthirdline\nfourthline";
        std::stringstream ss(input);
        std::string line;
        while(std::getline(ss, line))
        {
           if( line != "")
                 std::cout << line << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Output ([demo](http://ideone.com/cJv93)):

```
firstline
secondline
thirdline
fourthline
```

Comment: this doesn't do what OP is asking for, you split `input` by every single '\n', even if it yields the "correct" (printed) result in this case you should split it by two '\n'.

Comment: @refp: It does do what OP is asking, but differently.

Comment: "I have been trying to split a string by double newlines", nowhere are you splitting by double newlines.

Comment: @refp: As I said I did that differently.

Comment: @refp: He is, it's just that the way he output it didn't make if very clear.  Here's a slight modification of his code that clarifies it a bit: http://ideone.com/n3c5Q

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I don't agree, no matter if you give me a hundred "slightly modified" snippets. **;-)** I don't consider the above to be helpful when trying to split one string using a sequence longer than one char, which is why I down-voted it.

Comment: @refp: What is the objective in the question? Is my answer an alternative solution?

Comment: @refp: Also, you kept repeating that my solution doesn't do "double line" splitting. I would say that is short-sightedness, because my solution doesn't do even single line splitting. It does job the differently which I have said in my answer.

Comment: @refp: Therefore I think your downvote is "discouraging" *alternative* solutions.

Comment: As I interpreted the question it is to split a string by every two new lines, it isn't *"mimic the same output as I got doing something different"*, and as I tried to say earlier - it doesn't solve the op's question. What if the input string contains "\n\n\n\n", are you still sure that this is an alternative solution and not just something that happened to work for that specific testcase?

Comment: @refp: *What if the input string contains "\n\n\n\n", are you still sure that this is an alternative solution*?... YES:  http://ideone.com/9Qozf

Comment: @Nawaz I'm not, please add statements so that the `[]` are printed around each group - without adding any extra variables (because your snippet needs to be modified to support true splitting by more than one character).

Comment: @refp: What do you think the output *must* be in that case? More importantly, why do you think so? The question doesn't talk about `"\n\n\n\n"` after all. So how do you come to know the expected output in case of `"\n\n\n\n"`? What if there is `\n\n\n\n\n`? Is there enough information in the question, to conclude the expected output in such cases?

Comment: @Nawaz: this code needs to ignore every second (consecutive) empty line.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Is that hard to do with `stringstream`? I showed how to use `stringstream`. And he can use that knowledge to achieve the desired behavior, which is not very clear from his question, as of now, for all input cases. My point is that you can avoid splitting the string.